# SQL Report Builder 3.0 - generate multiple reports between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, reporting

I've done some research on this but I don't think I'm typing in the right thing to find what I am after.....

Basically I have a working report which displays the order information based on the OrderID (parameter).. so 1001, 1002 etc. What im now trying to do is group all of these together between a date range..

So for example I could have 50 unique Orders in a specified week. I want to now generate a 50 page document (PDF), displaying the full Order Report for each unique order. NOT IN A TABLE VIEW.

so my question is: is this even possible and if yes, could someone please point me in the right direction..... Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass date range as parameters to query, bring bring back data to report, and use grouping controls to show those 50 reports on every page.
Use can use 'List' for that purpose. Put existing report into a list and just pass complete data source to the list.

If you can pull single order data, say order number 1001, in a single row, then it's quite easy to build report.
Otherwise you may have to use sub reports to show tabular data from each order.

Let me know if you have any difficulties doing this.